# python manage.py collectstatic only detects first modification of the day

Tags: python, django

When running python manage.py collectstatic, it only detects the first change every day.

I have python-dateutil 2.2 and django-storages 1.1.8 installed, AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA=True in settings, tried setting TIME_ZONE=None.

It seems the modification detection is just using the date. What else can I try to make sure my modifications are detected with the entire timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the s3boto.py file as described here fixed it!

http://code.larlet.fr/django-storages/pull-request/83/converting-s3-last-modified-time-to-local/diff